Какой сетью убрать фоновую музыку из аудио?
я попробовал найти нейросеть, которую можно запустить у себя и "скормить" ей какое то кол-во аудиофайлов, в которых смешаны голос и музыка. (это аудиокниги со слишком громким музыкальным сопровождением)
Нашел статью на тему "нейросетей, которые отделяют вокал от музыки" - но это оказалась "чистая реклама", типа "10 минут бесплатно, апотом у нас есть вот такие то тарифные планы".
Не могли бы вы посоветовать, где вообще имеет смысл искать такие сети? Или какую то вводную статью на эту тему?
Задача явно не очень сложная (стартапов, которые убирают фоновый шум при zoom или skype-звонке - уже  нессколько, и появились они достаточно давно. Да и материала для обучения сетки - много!). Кажется, я просто не там ищу :-)
Спасибо!

Бесплатные нейросети надо искать на Hugging Face. Вот пример https://huggingface.co/tasks/audio-to-audio разделения двух голосов в два аудио. Может что и для музыки найдется.

"Задача явно не очень сложная" - месье шутник

@AlexanderLonberg - спасибо за наводку, поищу! пока нашел вот это - https://github.com/itkho/music-remover , разбираюсь

@user7860670 Смотря с каким качеством это нужно. Совсем выпилить музыку реально сложно. Но в данном случае такого вроде и не требуется. Если что-то останется, то не страшно. А такая задача уже гораздо проще.
